# Calcium hydroxide and why there are parenthesis

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Basics but in calcium hydroxide Ca(OH)2 ,
*Where the 2 is a subscript what do the parenthesis symbolize? Why isnt it just CaOH2??

Comment: $\ce{CaOH2}$ has one calcium, one oxygen and two hydrogen atoms. $\ce{(OH)2}$ means that there are two OH groups.

Answer (score 3):

Parenthesis in a chemical formula indicate that the elements inside them form a group. If followed by a sub-scripted number then there are that number of the group attached.

So Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> is different from CaOH<sub>2</sub>. It has an extra oxygen.